# I want a word for one who is in a relationship

Tags: word-request, idiomatic-language

> Intimate relationships are very delicate and so ..... in such relationships should always meet the following conditions.

What word is the most idiomatic choice for the blank above: participants? participator? etc?

Comment: You're making this more difficult than it needs to be. Pronouns are your friends: _Intimate relationships are very delicate, so **those** in such relationships should always meet the following conditions._

Comment: @J.R. those who are in ...?

Comment: @J.R. Please make that an answer, so the community may vote on it.

Comment: @JamesK - It doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: It absolutely answers the question "Which word is the most idiomatic choice for the blank" answer "those".

Answer (score 3):

The person someone is married to or living with as if married to them, or having a sexual relationship with can be called [a partner](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/partner):

> ... so (both) the partners ..  should always meet the following conditions: ...

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

**Participant** is one who is taking part in an activity or event. In that sentence *intimate relationships* don't refer to such an activit/event.

**Participator** is a non-existent word, it is most likely a lexical gap.

But as for the missing word, I would go for **parties**.

> **party**
>
> > **3** *group of people* [also + plural verb British English] - a group of people who go somewhere together or do a job together

Relationships are no job, of course, but it seems logical to me to use the plural form (parties) in that sentence.

In case you don't like this alternative, you can also use *partners, lovers* etc.

Comment: participant in a relationship does not ring any bells for me...

Comment: So "parties to such relationships" or "parties in such relationships"?

Comment: You should say *parties in such relationships*.

Comment: "parties to such relationships" in way more frequent on google search.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this more difficult than it needs to be. Pronouns are your friends:

> Intimate relationships are very delicate, so **those** in such relationships should always meet the following conditions.

– J.R

Answer (score 0):

Why not just say *people* if what you really want is to fill in that blank? It's first and foremost people who form these romantic relationships, isn't it:

> Intimate relationships are very delicate, so **people** engaged in such relationships should always meet the following conditions.